# Cheapest marker in java serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

I am using ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method to serialize a tree. The datatype of tree is generic, can be integer as well as a complex 'Student' object. But I need to 'mark' a null pointer, a pointer which I will use to mark leave node.
eg:

```
  if (node.item == null) {
     oos.writeObject('SOMEMARKER');
     return;
  }
```

My question is what can be the cheapest ( space wise ) way to mark a null ? EG: use boolean ?
eg: oos.writeObject(`true`) ?

Comment: The cheapest would be writeByte(int val) but it depends on how you can interpret the data stream.

Comment: Why do you need markers? Shouldn't Object Input/Output streams take care of it automatically?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic and Peter Lawrey are correct. There's a fairly common misconception that `null` is reserved for end of stream in Serialization. It isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to mark a `null` is to use a null.

```
oos.writeObject(null);
```

You can mark with a boolean but `writeObject(true)` uses more space than just passing a `null`.

```
if (node.item == null) {
    oos.writeByte(0);
} else {
    oos.writeByte(1);
    oos.writeObject(note.item);
}

// to read
Item item = ois.readByte() == 0 ? null : (Item) ois.readObject();
```

However, since you are using Java Serailization which is pretty inefficient anyway I wouldn't worry about it and keep things simple.

```
oos.writeObject(item.node);

// to read
Item item = (Item) ois.readObject();
```